# Implementation of Excel's Array Formula in c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel, consider if we input the array formula as `"=A1:C3-C1:C2"`, it will calculate the results in and returns in the selected cells in the form `"A1-C1,B1-C1,C1-C1,A2-C2,B2-C2,C2-C2"`.

How to implement this in c#?

Comment: Are you working with the excel interop or just trying to do the same in a c# array without excel?

Comment: i want to achieve it in C# array without excel